# DMARC/DKIM and non-ASCII characters

Tags: ascii, html-email, exchange-server, dkim, dmarc

I'm not very familiar with the details of sending email but I'm getting the runaround between a vendor whose system automatically generates outgoing emails with the content I have configured and the Outlook engineers at my organization who have said that Microsoft has told them the presence of non-ASCII characters in the email are causing DKIM to fail, and that sending emails in UNICODE format is a workaround.

Is one of these parties clearly wrong? What specifics would you need to know in order to determine that?

Comment: You couldn't just try what they have suggested and see if that works?

Comment: Spam traps, unfortunately, are black boxes by design. You can't see into them. So it's just trial and error. So I'm not sure you can get specific knowable repeatable answers here on this topic.

Comment: @Nathan the message itself isn't created by code I own. But as it turned out I did find that the content (which I do control) did have spaces (of all things!) that were somehow coming out as non-ASCII. So we were able to fix.